# Serving images and saving cookies on the user's machine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cookies

I know it's possible to plant a cookie on a user's machine when he is loading an image from my server, by altering the apache settings.

However, I want to know if it's possible to include an image in HTML code that will have parameters in it and I can activate some script to log these parameters, for example:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/myimage.jpg?somcode=123&customer=abcd" />
```

In return to loading the picture, I would like to save a cookie on the user's machine with `somecode=123` and `customer=abcd` and also to save this info in my db.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .jpg for the filename, just use .php. Then you don't have to mess around with server configurations and normal image files still get served correctly:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/myimage.php?somcode=123&customer=abcd" />
```

Then your myimage.php file:

```
<?php
// Your tracking and processing code here
$customer = $_GET['customer'];

// Then, either:
header("Location: /urlpath/to/the/actual/image.jpg"); /* Option 1 */

// OR:
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
readfile("/filepath/to/the/actual/image.jpg"); /* Option 2 */
```

I prefer Option 1 because it allows your web server to very efficiently serve the actual image instead of PHP (Option 2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could do that, Just make apache treat the .jpg extension as php files.

You could add the following to your .htaccess file in the specific folder (don't put it in the root or it will treat all JPGs this way);

```bash
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .jpg
```